# Prime ideal and ring of integers

Tags: number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am reading an introduction into algebraic number theory and struggling on the following sentence:

> Let $M/F$ be an extension of number fields, and $\mathfrak p$ an prime ideal of $\mathcal{O}_F$. Then $\mathcal{O}_M \mathfrak p$ is an ideal in $\mathcal{O}_M$ which is no longer a prime ideal in general.

My question is: what does the notation $\mathcal{O}_M\mathfrak p$ mean? I think it means the product of the two ideals, but then why is $\mathfrak p$ also an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_M$? Why is $\mathcal{O}_M\mathfrak p$ even an ideal of $\mathcal{O}_M$?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It means you consider the ideal in a larger ring.

Comment: But why is it an ideal in the larger ring?

Comment: I'm not sure about the notation: but suppose you have rings $S \subseteq R$ with $S$ a subring of $R$ and consider an ideal $I$ in $S$. Then $I$ is not necessarily an ideal in $R$ (consider $\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Q}$) but you can consider the ideal in $R$ generated by $I$, and one denotes this by $RI$. I think something similar is happening in your situation but I'm not familiar with the notation so I can't be sure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Maybe someone with familiarity in algebraic number theory can confirm this :)

Comment: It is how $\epsilon$-$\delta$ pointed out. Whenever you have a morphism of rings $f \colon S \rightarrow R$, the image of an ideal in $S$ does not need to be an ideal (see for example inclusion of the integers in the rational numbers). Therefore one needs to close it which means using the ideal generated by the image. Your ring extension is a particular case of this.

Comment: @ThorWittich thanks!

Comment: To see why a prime ideal in $\mathcal O_F$ need not extend to a prime ideal in $\mathcal O_M$, consider $F = \mathbf Q$ and $M = \mathbf Q(i)$. When $p$ is a prime number with $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$, the ideal $\mathfrak p = p\mathbf Z$ is prime in $\mathcal O_F = \mathbf Z$ but $\mathfrak p\mathcal O_M = p\mathbf Z[i]$ is not prime in $\mathbf Z[i]$ since $p$ is composite in $\mathbf Z[i]$. This reasoning also applies to $p = 2$.

Comment: Your notation $P.O_M$ means the ideal generated by $P$ in $O_M$. Even if P is prime in $O_F$, the extended ideal $P.O_M$  is not prime in general in $O_M$. The best popular example, I think, is what happens when extending $\mathbf Z$ to the ring of Gaussian integers $\mathbf Z[i]$. The theory of Dedekind rings deals in particular with the decomposition of $P.O_M$ into a product of prime ideals in $O_M$. See e.g. chap. 5 of P. Samuel's booklet "ANT".

Answer (score 0):

Question:"Why is $O_Mp$ even an ideal of $O_M$?"

Answer: If $\phi: A\rightarrow B$ is a map of commutative unital rings and $I$ is an ideal in $A$, you define $IB$ (or $BI$) to be the following ideal:

I1. $IB:=\{\sum_i b_ix_i$ with $b_i \in B, x_i:=\phi(y_i)$ with $y_i\in A\}.$

You may check that $IB\subseteq B$ is an abelian group with the property that  for
all $x\in IB, b\in B$ it follows $bx\in IB$. Hence $IB$ is an ideal in $B$.

As mentioned above: The standard example of a ring extension where the extension of a prime ideal is no longer a prime ideal is the extension

$\phi: A:=\mathbb{Z} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}[i]:=B$

let $I:=(2) \subseteq A$. The ideal $I$ is prime in $A$ but in $B$ there is a factorization $2=(1-i)(1+i)$, hence the ideal $IB$ equals $(1-i)(1+i)B$ which is no longer prime. If $p\neq 2$ is a prime with $p\equiv 1 (mod 4)$ there is an equality

$p=a^2+b^2=(a-ib)(a+ib)$ in $B$ for two integers $a,b\geq 1$

Hence the prime ideal $(p)B$ is no longer prime in $B$. This is Theorem 1.1.1 in Neukirch's book "Algebraic number theory". In Theorem 1.4 in the same book the prime elements in $B$ are classified, and a prime number $p \in A$
remains prime in $B$ iff $p\equiv 3 (mod 4)$. If $p \equiv 1(mod 4)$ with $p=a^2+b^2$ it follows the elements $a+ib, a-ib$ are prime elements in $B$,
hence

I1. $(p)B=(a+ib)(a-ib)B$ gives rise to the decomposition

I2. $(p)B=\mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2$

with $\mathfrak{p}_1=(a+ib)$ and $\mathfrak{p}_2=(a-ib)$. Here $\mathfrak{p}_i$ are prime ideals in $B$.

You get a canonical map of rings

I3. $A/(p) \rightarrow B/(p)B \cong B/\mathfrak{p}_1\mathfrak{p}_2 \cong B/\mathfrak{p}_1 \oplus B/\mathfrak{p}_2$

and since $\mathfrak{p}_i$ are non-zero prime ideals it follows they are maximal ideals. Hence the ring $B/(p)B$ is a direct sum of the fields $B/\mathfrak{p}_i$. Since $A/(p):=\mathbb{F}_p$ is the finite field with $p$
elements it follows there is an isomorphism

I4. $B/\mathfrak{p}_i \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^{r_i}}$

for some integer  $r_i \geq 2$. You may calculate the integer $r_i$ explicitly.